# how to find click event of tree and ID of selected record

Tags: javascript, python, odoo-8

I have a view as it shows the image 1 in attachment,

[image 1](http://www.noelshack.com/2016-51-1482574429-img-1.png)
it is tree editable in a form, when I click on a line to modify I want to know the ID of the selected record so the event of click on The line so that I can display in another tree the information related to the selected recording as it shows the image 2 in the attached piece. 
[image 2](http://www.noelshack.com/2016-51-1482574439-img-2.png)

thank you.

Here is the view xml code:

```
    <record id="view_ouvrage_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">devis.form</field>
        <field name="model">planning.devis</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Devis" version="7.0">
                <group col="8" string="Information Devis">
                    <field name="numero" colspan="4"/>
                    <field name="date_devis" colspan="4"/>
                    <field name="description" colspan="8"/>
                </group>

                <group string="Information Ouvrages">
                    <field name="devis_ouvrage" nolabel="1">
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                            <field name="reference"/>
                            <field name="description"/>
                            <field name="unite"/>
                            <field name="cadence"/>
                            <field name="qte"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </group>
                <group string="Details Ouvrages">
                    <field name="devis_ouvrage_detail" nolabel="1">
                        <field name="ouvrage_materiel" nolabel="1">
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <field name="designation"/>
                                <field name="qte"/>
                                <field name="prixu"/>
                                <field name="unite"/>
                                <field name="total" sum="Total"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: your question is not very clear to me, please re-phrase to outline exactly what your problem is

Comment: show your html for the table row. Is there any identifier attached to the dom for the rows

Comment: Add the HTML code for the current tree

Comment: I added the pictures and the xml code of the view.

Answer (score 0):

If this tree is generated by your code, just add the id to onclick event like `onclick="javascript:onClickEvent(id_xxx)"`